# Use zipped virtualenv

Tags: python, bash, pip, virtualenv, conda

I'd like to create a virtual environment, zip it up, and execute code using the zipped virtual environment on another machine; it seems to be possible based on [this article](https://florianwilhelm.info/2016/10/python_udf_in_hive/).

However, I'm having trouble and sourcing a virtualenv even locally using the technique described in the article.

```
$ conda create -y -n my_test python=3.5 numpy pandas
$ zip -r env.zip ~/anaconda3/envs/my_test
$ source env.zip/lib/python3.5/venv/scripts/common/activate
-bash: env.zip/lib/python3.5/venv/scripts/common/activate: Not a directory
$ tar cvfhz env.tgz ~/anaconda3/envs/my_test
$ source env.tgz/lib/python3.5/venv/scripts/common/activate
-bash: env.tgz/lib/python3.5/venv/scripts/common/activate: Not a directory
```

I've tried this on Mac OS X 10.13.6 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: [virtualenv's aren't portable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+portable) and they aren't distribution/deployment mechanisms. Recreate a venv in the target directory/host or use a different distribution/deployment.

Comment: Adding to what @phd posted - the source command you execute will not work; you can't treat a zip or tar archive as part of the filesystem. The path `myarchive.zip/somescript` is thus invalid. It works for the author of the article you posted only because Hive will automatically unpack the archives added via `ADD ARCHIVE`. However, even after extraction, the venv will be usable only in identical setups on identical machines and when put in the same directory; it's cheaper just to create a new venv.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: The zipped packages might work , You have to copy those zipped packages to python local site-packages folder but certain packages like pandas which depends on `C` throws error depends on the OS build. Like pandas compiled on ubuntu won't work on AWS EMR machines with Cent OS.

Comment: As far as I understand [pex](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex) does pretty much this.

Comment: I'd never heard of pex, that's a great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conda create **--copy** -y -n my_test python=3.5 numpy pandas